# Voltage amplifier stage in Douglas Self's parallel op-amp audio amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, audio

I'm looking at making Douglas Self's parallel op-amp audio amplifier ([link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwirgc2ksIqCAxUFMDQIHcCwBUgQFnoECBcQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.physicsforums.com%2Fattachments%2Fdouglas_self_elektor_amp5532_compressed-pdf.254881%2F&usg=AOvVaw0nC43peZf7Po8gK7OQGR3O&opi=89978449)), and there's a few things I don't understand in the voltage amplifier stage (schematic below). He says the 22.7 dB amplification is split into three parts to spread the gain across several NE5532 op-amps (ICs 1, 2A, and 3B). The output of IC3A goes to the power amplifier stage. My questions are:

- What's the purpose of R8 and R9?
- What's the purpose of R14 and R17? A resistor in this location isn't "standard" in a non-inverting amplifier
- The input to IC6 is the output of the amplifier, it appears to be an integrator, so I guess the purpose is to remove any DC offset at the output. I would've thought there'd be a simpler way to implement the same purpose, does anyone know why it's implemented this way?

He says the gain is split like this because the NE5532 doesn't have amazing noise characteristics, and this topology minimises noise. I was thinking of just replacing ICs 1, 2, and 3 with a single OP177 with the same total gain, would this be a terrible idea?

Thanks in advance

[image: Voltage amplifier stage]

Comment: Simon Coop - Hi, In order to comply with the Stack Exchange [rule for referencing](/help/referencing), please can you edit the question & add the link to the original source webpage / PDF etc. for that schematic? Thanks.

Comment: Why IC6? It's  a Doug Self design, never use one component when 10 will do.

Comment: @Neil_UK hmmm. I worked with Doug years ago when he designed analogue mixers for Soundcraft in North London. Those designs are extremely efficient in parts usage, for the function and performance they give. If you want to see a mixer with 5 times as many parts doing not much more, look at something designed by Studer ....

Comment: from the look of it, I'd say that IC6 is a servo stage which keeps output offset voltage at zero. Means you don't need half a ton of blocking caps and maximises headroom. He used the same technique in his rather excellent mic amp designs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. R8 and R9 are resistors to stop the two op-amp outputs from being short-circuited together and average the signal. The output of two op-amps fed with same signal will never be equal, due to manufacturing tolerances of real world components. For example the op-amps have different output DC offset and the resistors have at least a few ohms difference, and the capacitor could have 5% or 10% tolerance.
2. R14 and R17 are not related to the circuit being an inverting amplifier. They are isolation resistors for implementing a dual-feedback circuit to drive capacitive or unknown loads, which the op-amp can't handle without help from external compensation circuitry. See how the op-amp is driving some sort of output connector so user of a circuit can put any kind of load, or maybe a cable that has a lot of capacitance, so it's just a circuit to keep the op-amp stable. You can even find this circuit in the OP177 data sheet.
3. Audio people call that a DC servo. It is a simple inverting integrator that senses the output signal and outputs an adjustment signal to the input to keep output DC voltage at zero.

And about replacing NE5532 with OP177, that's not a good idea unless you know what the circuit requires from the op-amp, and can the op-amp do what the circuit requires. NE5532 is a classic bipolar audio op-amp with 10 MHz of bandwidth. OP177 is a bipolar precision op-amp with 1 MHz of bandwidth. If the circuit is designed to require bandwidth and slew rates of NE5532, then it can't be replaced with a slower op-amp. Same also goes for bipolar VS FET op-amps, there are circuits that are designed for NE5532 and circuits designed for TL072 for example and you can't exchange the them vice versa because everything around the op-amps such as resistor values are designed to what the op-amp needs for proper operation.

There are many reasons to split the gain into multiple sections. For example it seems approximately total gain of 22dB is required. You need to have the op-amp working at suitable margin at the signal bandwidth you are interested. The op-amp must also be able to have fast enough slew rate to be able to output the signal with the required bandwidth at required amplitude.

Answer (score 2):

The resistors R8 and R9 are both connected to the non-inverting input of the operational IC2A forming a summing LP filter. IC3B with R12, R13, R14 and C8 together with R15, R16 R17, C9, IC3A, form a LP filter. IC6 is a Miller integrator however in this case it acts as an LP filter whose output is again filtered by the passive T filter and summed to the signal coming from C2.

[image]

Comment: Are the outputs of IC1A and IC1B added or averaged? They're going into the non-inverting input of IC2, doesn't a summing amplifier use the inverting input? Thanks for the useful comments, I wish I could give a vote to both answers.

Comment: @SimonCoop it's explained at the bottom of page 18 of the linked article that the outputs of IC1A and IC1B are averaged to reduce noise (on the basis that the noise is uncorrelated). I'm sceptical.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Outputs 1 and 7 are averaged through the resistors R8 and R9 and the resistance of the non-inverting input of IC2A which, however, can be considered infinite.
[image]